# Jade Include doesn't render included page content

Tags: node.js, templates, express, pug

I'm trying do an app with Node/Express/Jade/Stylus.

The problem is that Jade won't render the content of an included file.

Here are the files:

layout.jade:

```
doctype 5
html
  block head
    head
      title= title
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')

body
  header
    block header

  #main-container
    block content

  footer
    block footer
```

index.jade:

```
extends layout

include helpers/header

block content 
  form#form-login
```

helpers/header.jade:

```
extends ../layout

block header
  #test
    p Hello World
    img(src="images/Logo.jpg" alt="Logo")
```

The rendered page is blank. In the page there is nothing. The image url is right, so tha's not part of the problem. I checked the page code, and header.jade was completely ignored.

I checked if the header.jade is loaded, and it is loaded (I tried putting an error in it).

Here the code of the rendered page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>Title</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
     </head>
     <body>
       <header></header>
       <div id="main-container">
         <form id="form-login"></form>
       </div>
       <footer></footer>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a block doesn't propagate properly from an include to a layout (I'm not overly familiar with Jade so this might be intended behaviour), because this seems to work:

```
// index.jade
extends layout

block header
  include helpers/header

block content 
  form#form-login
```

Also, you shouldn't use `extends ../layout` in your header include, otherwise your layout file will be rendered twice.